# Forcing Date format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the the following date format 02/02/02 and I need this format to save to  a csv file to  be uploaded.  How do I program excel to not force the date back to 02/02/2002 ?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSV and the date format will change as you noted.  Once your data has been imported then you can change the format back to the 2 digit year format you're looking for.
Select a range of cells and right click, pick format and change to the format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the column that holds the date field
2. Select **Format Cells** --> Select the **Number** tab
3. Select **Custom**
4. Type **mm/dd/yy**
5. Select OK

This will automatically force the format to retain the mm/dd/yy